# How to make password prompt to the root shell accept any password?

Tags: linux, password, root, serial-port, busybox

Board running embedded Linux version 2.6.26.5 and Busybox 1.10.2
When accessing board via a serial console port, the access to root shell is password protected. How to make the password prompt accept **any** password?  As I know there is an `inittab` method, in my system the inittab is missing.
Probably it's also possible to adjust login code in busybox login utils, what code need be edited for this?

Comment: You can probably achieve what you want with a PAM module.

Comment: PAM module is not set. I would try another way, manually edit /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files, but in my case both passwd and shadow files are in form of broken symlinks (inode/symlink), targeting /tmp/passwd and /tmp/shadow.